# Lenovo ThinkPad T410s dual monitor resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, thinkpad

I have a couple of questions about the Lenovo ThinkPad 410s and its dual external monitor support.

When the T410s is connected to two external displays, what resolutions can it support on the two external displays?

Also, when the 410s is connected to the ThinkPad Mini Dock (Series 3), what kind of resolutions can I support on two external displays (via the dock)?  Are the resolutions supported dependent on the computer connected to the dock (i.e. the 410s) or the dock itself?

Comment: If you are not getting any answers here, try asking at the unofficial ThinkPad forums or the Lenovo forums.  http://forum.thinkpads.com/

Answer (score 2):

Very belated answer, but the video card in pretty much any Thinkpad (yes, even the X series) is capable of running monitors at the highest resolution that particular connector will support - so for all practical purposes, as high as you want on DVI or DisplayPort (2560x1600 with no problem), or whatever the practical limit on VGA is, which I honestly don't know, but it should be able to give you 1920x1200 at least.